# Encrypted access tokens - expiration date

Tags: authentication, token

My idea is to use encrypted tokens - where upon authentication (with username and password), backend would encrypt user_id, timestamp and an SHA-256 over those, base 64 encode it and return to the client as an access token. This way I can eliminate the need for a persistent token store.

This is similar to the scheme described in [this article](http://eversystems.eu/Document/15/Sessionless_Authentication_with_Encrypted_Tokens) (there are some differences though).

The logic I would like to have, is that **when token is used constantly** (i.e. longest interval between subsequent API calls is no longer than N), **user shouldn't be prompted for the reauthentication**.

The issue is that encrypted token's validity cannot be extended, since **changing the timestamp means the value of the token changes**.

I can see the following solutions:

1) Each time token is validated, issue a new token and return in to the client. On every request, client would forget about the previous token, and store the new one instead.

- **+** solves the issue
- **+** logic on the client is rather straightforward
- **--** for one user, multiple tokens would be valid at the same time

2) Do implement an API endpoint which would accept an expired  token, and would issue a new token in return. This endpoint would have some configurable value M, so if token is expired by more than M, new token wouldn't be issued.

- **+** solves the issue
- **+** for one user, only one token would be valid at the same time
- **--** logic on the client is a bit more complicated - needs to refresh token.

Is there another solution, based on encrypted tokens? (I know we can get around that issue with regular, persisted tokens).

Comment: You may want to consider changing the title.  You are proposing using a cryptographic hash SHA-256, which is not an encryption algorithm.

Comment: In the first sentence I mentioned the whole thing will be encrypted before doing a base 64

Comment: in the link you provide, the author uses a different process to create the cookie: create a hash of the ID and date, THEN encode it, followed by encoding for web (base 64). I think you created some confusion when you changed the order in your question.

Comment: I didn't change the order (I mean I didn't edited the question).  Anyway,  to clarify,  what I'm doing is that: AES(user_id + timestamp + SHA-256(user_id + timestamp) )

Comment: You may want to look at this question: [Generating authentication token from PHP sessions](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80083/generating-authentication-token-from-php-sessions/80111)

Answer (score 1):

You could encrypt the `userid:timestamp:hash`, base64 it, and send it as a cookie. On every token validated, recalculate a new one with a new timestamp and send back.

Record every invalid token for a user, and invalidate every token coming for the same user and same IP address for a period. This complicates the life of anyone trying to bruteforce tokens.

You don't have to care too much about a user having more than one valid token, only that you are talking to the same user. If a user opens multiple tabs on your site, multiple valid tokens will happen.

Comment: Actually,  the token is encrypted.  So I'd get a user ID, timestamp and a hash,  encrypt it and only the base 64 encode it

Comment: I read it too fast... I edited the answer.